# How to remove an array containing certain strings from another array in Python

Tags: python

Example:

```
a = ['abc123','abc','543234','blah','tete','head','loo2']
```

So I want to filter out from the above array of strings the following array `b = ['ab','2']`

I want to remove strings containing 'ab' from that list along with other strings in the array so that I get the following:

```
a = ['blah', 'tete', 'head']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
[i for i in a if not any(x in i for x in b)]
```

This returns:

```
['blah', 'tete', 'head']
```

Comment: It gives the original 'a' values

Comment: @LP What do you mean?

Comment: @Haidro your first iteration was wrong. +1 But the readability of this one is horrible :)

Comment: @limelights I'm on my phone :p

Comment: @Haidro my bad, had a typo; thanks for the quick reply from you phone :)

Comment: @LP Yea, sorry about that. I must have just fixed that after you commented. Anyways, glad I helped :)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> a = ['abc123','abc','543234','blah','tete','head','loo2']
>>> b = ['ab','2']
>>> [e for e in a if not [s for s in b if s in e]]
['blah', 'tete', 'head']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
newA = []
for c in a:
    for d in b:
        if d not in c:
            newA.append(c)
            break
a = newA
```

Comment: Although this is correct, it is a much slower solution (albeit more readable:)). Just a tip, you can use `break` after the `if ...` as you don't need to search anymore (this is what `any` does, btw).

Comment: Actually you are right and it is necessary to avoid adding twice.